# Create stream of Integer values and add to Integer[]

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying:

```
Integer[] arr = new Random().ints(1,100).distinct()
                .limit((long) 10).toArray();

java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer[]
```

I'm confused because `ints()` returns an `IntStream` which should be a stream of `Integer` values correct?

Does anyone know how to do this with streams?

Comment: `IntStream#toArray()` returns `int[]`, not `Integer[]`. While primitives will be autoboxed when appropriate, the same does not happen for _arrays_ of primitives.

Comment: Right there [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray()).

Comment: Hmm, why did you delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77863485/12671057)? That's not nice, after an answerer spent time on it.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `toArray()`, it returns a primitive `int[]` array instead of an `Integer[]` array<sup>[***1***](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray())</sup>. One way to fix the issue is to use *[`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--)* method.

```java
Integer[] arr = new Random().ints(1, 100).distinct()
                .limit(10)
                .boxed()
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/xD2a7gDGZ)***

##### What `boxed()` does to the stream?

> The `boxed()` method is used to convert a stream of primitive values (like in our case an `IntStream`) to a stream of their corresponding wrapper objects (like a `Stream<Integer>`), allowing us to perform operations that require objects rather than primitive values.

---

Let's break it down into steps of what happens when you call `boxed()` on an `IntStream`:

- The `IntStream` contains a sequence of primitive `int` values.
- When you call `boxed()`, it creates a new `Stream<Integer>` instance.
- The `boxed()` method iterates through the original `IntStream` and, for each `int` value, creates a new `Integer` object containing that value.
- The new `Stream<Integer>` contains the `Integer` objects that correspond to the original `int` values in the `IntStream`.

Comment: Can you explain what boxed() is doing to the stream?

Comment: @notaorb Java has primitive types and reference types. An `int` is a primitive type (though note `int[]`, like all arrays, is a reference type; i.e., an object). Unfortunately, primitive types cannot be used as generic type arguments, so you can't have something like a `Stream<int>`. That's why there's the `IntStream` primitive stream specialization. It's also why there are reference equivalents to primitives (e.g., `Integer` vs `int`). Going from the primitive type to the reference type is known as "boxing". Boxing and unboxing (the opposite of boxing) can happen automatically.

Comment: Having to go from an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` (i.e., go from a primitive `int` stream to a boxed `Integer` stream) is a common occurrence, so they added the `boxed()` method to the `IntStream` interface. It's basically shorthand for `mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i))` (or just `mapToObj(i -> i)` due to autoboxing).

Comment: Why does everyone suggest to insert `.boxed()` instead of changing the type of `arr` to `int[]`?

Comment: @Holger good point. I can tell you about why I used it and added it as my answer. It striked my mind as a first option and I somehow wanted to keep the requirement as added by OP. But it's a good point. You should definetely add it as one answer if you like

Answer (score 4):

IntStream is a stream for basic type int, not for boxed type Integer.

To generate an Integer array, call the boxed method first.

```
Integer[] arr = new Random().ints(1,100).distinct()
                .limit((long) 10).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```